# A list of scala "global" functions?

Tags: scala

There are some "global" functions in scala, for example:

```
print
println
classOf
format
```

The first 2 are actually Console's singleton methods, the last comes from java.lang.String.format.

I believe there are some more, may somebody list all of them, or point out where I can find corresponding API documentation ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

They're all defined in the [`scala.Predef`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$.html) *object*.